# CC3Node - Detect touch on subnode of CC3Node

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos3d

Hi i have been exploring cocos3D and i was wondering how can i detect which submode of main CC3Node was touched. I am using following code:

```
rezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: @"BeachBall.pod"];
n = (CC3MeshNode*)[rezNode getNodeNamed: @"BeachBall"];
n.isOpaque = YES;
[self configureAndAddTemplate: n];
```

this will create main node, then i link a variable to child node

```
self.childNode =(CC3Node*)[n getMeshNodeNamed: @"BeachBall-submesh1"];
self.childNode.isTouchEnabled=YES;
self.childNode.visible=YES;
```

Now i want to detect touch on that particular node. My touch methods are firing but i am guessing how to check if touch was on self.childNode.

**Edit:**
In cocos3D programming guide it is mentioned

> Once these two steps have been completed, the
>   nodeSelected:byTouchEvent:at: callback method of your customized
>   CC3World subclass will automatically be invoked on each touch event.
>   This callback includes the CC3Node instance that was touched, the type
>   of touch, and the 2D location of the touch point, in the local
>   coordinates of the CC3Layer.

First step is to integrate touch delegates and second is to set node property to visible and touchesEnabled. I have implemented both the steps but still this method **nodeSelected:byTouchEvent:at:** is not firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer myself. As mentioned in test project we have to call `pickNodeFromTapAt: or pickNodeFromTouchEvent:at:` to automatic invoke `nodeSelected:byTouchEvent:at:`. What i was doing is that is was calling this `pickNodeFromTouchEvent:at:` in **touchEvent**  **touchBegan** and i was overriding that method in my scene. That was the problem i don't have to override it as it is already declared in CC3Scene. So as soon as i removed the overrided method from my CustomSecene Class `nodeSelected:byTouchEvent:at:` was fired.

Hope this helps somebody